# Symfony2 CompilerPassInterface set service via setArgument

Tags: symfony

To ovveride some vendor's service and set my custom class I am using CompilerPass.
I also need to ovveride arguments passed to this class. I tried like this:

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('vendor.service');
    $definition->setClass('Acme\DemoBundle\MyClass');

    $definition->setArguments(array(
        'my_service_id'
    ));
}
```

Error here is that `Acme\DemoBundle\MyClass` retrieves string instead of object.

How to pass custom service `my_service_id` (defined in other bundle) or in worst case `service.container`?

Comment: Found the correct solution:
`new \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference('service.id')`